# catching JS log on xcode console using web view

Tags: javascript, iphone, ios, uiwebview, console

can any one help me in catching the JS log message on xcode console, JS has to be run on web view (UIWebView).

Answer (score 2):

to receive message from one webview use custom url scheme just like "log:yourlogmsg"

js code

```
window.location = "log:yourlogmsg";
```

use

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType
```

and return false;

Comment: where to write this line, i mean in which class and method  window.location = "log:yourlogmsg";